# cat_is_ancestor_of() for custom taxonomies

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to use cat_is_ancestor_of() for custom taxonomy categories but it's not working. Is there any other way to check if a category is child of another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`term_is_ancestor_of()`](http://queryposts.com/function/term_is_ancestor_of/). That is the function `cat_is_ancestor_of()` is calling:

```
term_is_ancestor_of( $parent, $child, 'taxonomy_name' );
```